# View's origin confuse my project

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I got a project ( I' ve already finished it ) I did a uialert view into. When I started my app and pressed the alert view button, the alert view came from the top, not from the middle of the screen. I set the view s origin s to the middle, and it s worked, but if went into a subview and after backed to the start view, the alert view came again from the top left.
Then I set my view s origin back to the top left, and it s still works the same wrong mode( app start: okey, after go into subview and back it s wrong) .

If I start my app,and just tap the alert button it works fine ( appears from the middle with the right animation ), after I go any subview , it s confuse, and I got a uitextfield, and map too in my subviews. If I click into the textfield, the "|" symbol to start writing, comes from the top left, and if I want to zoom in my text for just correct it, the loupe comes from the top left too, and it s really annoying. And if I watch the map, and there is a pin, and during the zooming in or out the pin disappears, when I stop it, it comes from the top left, or bottom right.

I don t know how to fix this problem, my mind is blowing.

I tried to fix it with code:

```
skroller.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
levels.layer.anchorPoint =  CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
```

but it still works wrong

If I click on the view , and show the size inspector it doesn t look like this:
[image](http://kepfeltoltes.hu/130108/Gbf0t_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png)

I don t see the Autosize, and example, and arrange. If I click on for example to attributes inspector it appeard for 0.00001 sec .

Comment: Should you not multiply by the size of the view? (Just a guess.)

Comment: I m sorry, I am 'newbie' I don t understand what you mean, I have to tell you one more thing, my "second" subview is a scrollview: [skroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1500, 220)];
    [skroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [skroller setPagingEnabled:YES]; this appears with setalpha 0-1 when I click on play button.

Comment: @Miklós: `skroller.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);` helyett írd ezt: `skroller.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5 * skroller.frame.size.width, 0.5 * skroller.frame.size.height);`

Comment: Oh ( de jó hogy magyar vagy :) ) nem tudom írhatok e magyarul itt . Miután ezt beírtam a teljes scroll view eltűnt, egyáltalán nem látszik semmi belőle

Comment: beírtam így: skroller.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0 * skroller.frame.size.width, 0 * skroller.frame.size.height); így már látszik jobb alul elscsúszva viszont  a probléma továbbra is fenn áll

Comment: @Miklós Nem szabad magyarul egyébként :D I'm heading over the docs in order to clarify my answer...

Comment: So I was wrong, apparently... Well, I'm not sure how to resolve this, after all.